# Image gallery with content below each image

Tags: views, media, nodes

I have created an image gallery using views and a custom content type, Photo. It has 2 rows of three images each. I have uploaded the 6 images via the Photo content type, added a body describing the images and then used the views module to create the gallery. However in the gallery only the images and their titles are visible. What i want is that the title should be displayed below and also the description for images should appear. Part of the problem may be solved through CSS, atleast that is what i think but how to get the description/ body (2-3 lines) to get displayed below each image in the gallery.

Comment: how have you created the view?

Comment: do you want your description content in a trimmed way like 250 to 280 letters or you cant fetch description??

Comment: Yes I have created the view

Comment: i am unable to fetch description...